# str.format() vs str %

Tags: python

I am not sure how important is this question.

I saw for the first time the `str %` operator here in people's questions, as I didn't know it and  always used `str.format()`, which was introduced in **Python 2.6**.

I.e.

```
'My age is {0}'.format(age)
```

vs

```
'My age is %d' % age
```

- Is one of them considered as more standard than the other?
- Does one of them work faster than the other?

Thanks!

Comment: `str.format()` is a lot more flexible and powerful. Don't know about faster, you'd have to compare a few things with `timeit`.

Comment: Also: [Python string formatting: % vs. `.format`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)